# Excel VBA Function gives error "Invalid procedure call or argument"

Tags: vba, excel

My colleague uses the function below to extract data from an Excel file generated by HP Quality Center. For some reason it works for him in Excel 2007 but not for me in Excel 2013.

I get the error **Invalid procedure call or argument**

I have tried a number of fixes like replacing ' and ", emptying the Tabledestination field, changing the pivot table version and many other things. I am not proficient with VBA at all so I don't know where else to put my hands beside where the debugger tells me to.

This is where the debugger gives the error:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Query1!R1C1:R5000C10", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Sheet4!R3C1", TableName:="Tabella_pivot1", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
```

The full code is below:

```
Sub QC_PostProcessing()
Dim MainWorksheet As Worksheet
' Make sure your worksheet name matches!
Set MainWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Query1")
Dim DataRange As Range
Set DataRange = MainWorksheet.UsedRange
' Now that you have the data in DataRange you can process it.

' Table Title
    Range("A1:J1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True

' Autofit
    Columns("A:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit

' Table grid
    Range("A1:J1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

' Pivot
    Dim Data_sht As Worksheet
    Dim StartPoint As Range
    Dim DataRange2 As Range
    Dim NewRange As String
    Set Data_sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Query1")
    Set StartPoint = Data_sht.Range("A1")
    Set DataRange2 = Data_sht.Range(StartPoint, StartPoint.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    NewRange = Data_sht.Name & "!" & _
    DataRange2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
    'Query1!R1C1:R5000C10"

    Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Query1!R1C1:R5000C10", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable _          ' variabile
        TableDestination:="Sheet4!R3C1", TableName:="Tabella_pivot1", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot1").PivotFields("Priority")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot1").PivotFields( _
        "Subject")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "Tabella_pivot1").PivotFields("Status"), "Count of Status", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot1").PivotFields("Status")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With

' Graph
    Range("K3").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot1").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet4!$A$3:$E$22")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft 200
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop -230.00
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleWidth 1.3270833333, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleHeight 1.3767362934, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft

' Rename sheets
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Sheets("Sheet4").Name = "Stats"
    Sheets("Query1").Select
    Sheets("Query1").Name = "Report"
    Sheets("Stats").Select
    Sheets("Stats").Move After:=Sheets(2)
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Report").Select
    Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

**Edit**: tried splitting the function as Graham suggested, got a Run-time error '424' Object required. Here is how I did the split.

**Edit2**: update the underneath code to the last version, it now gives the following error "Run-time error '1004': The PivotTable field name is not valid. To create a PivotTable report, you must use data that is organized as a list with labeled columns. If you are changing the name of a PivotTable field, you must type a new name for the field." on the line with the CreatePivotTable.

```
Dim pCache As PivotCache
Dim pTable As PivotTable
Dim pivotRange As Range
Dim tableRange As Range
Dim Data_sht2 As Worksheet
Set Data_sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set pivotRange = Data_sht.Range(Data_sht.Cells(1, 1), Data_sht.Cells(5000, 18))
Set tableRange = Data_sht2.Range(Data_sht2.Cells(3, 18), Data_sht2.Cells(1, 3))

Set pCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
         SourceData:=pivotRange)
Set pTable = pCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=tableRange, _
         TableName:="Tabella_pivot1")
```

Comment: Look up this [Stackoverflow: Issue with vba creating a pivot table, is this an excel version issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301158/issue-with-vba-creating-a-pivot-table-is-this-an-excel-version-issue)

Comment: @Jerry No, this is not an Excel version issue. I had already tried before with changing the version and also tried not using the field at all as Graham suggested.

Comment: Which statement gives the error now that you've split it out?

Comment: @Graham It's on the line "Set pivotRange". I declared the variable, my doubt is on the "Query1" and "Sheet4" on the next line. Before the ".range", is it supposed to be a variable that contains the sheet or I can write the sheet name? Query1 and Sheet4 are the sheet name, I suspect it might be an error due to that,

Comment: Where is the variable Query1 defined?  That's probably the issue there.

Comment: @Graham Almost there, defined all the sheets (also noticed that it called for a sheet that does not exist). Now it gives "Run-time error '1004': The PivotTable field name is not valid." on the line with the CreatePivotTable.

Comment: @Graham Managed to make it work, thank you for the help!

Comment: Please make sure you provide the answer to the community too :)

Comment: @Graham Already done, thanks again :-)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, you should post this as the Answer instead of editing the question - that way people who are searching for this can see that it's not an unanswered question.

Comment: @Graham Yes I know, it is already posted below as answer :P

Answer (score 1):

First of all, many thanks to @Graham who was able to help me fix part of the problem. To fix this problem, first I split the part of the code giving error as such.

```
Dim pCache As PivotCache
Dim pTable As PivotTable
Dim pivotRange As Range
Dim tableRange As Range
Dim Data_sht2 As Worksheet
Set Data_sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Set pivotRange = Data_sht.Range(Data_sht.Cells(1, 1), Data_sht.Cells(5000, 10))
Set tableRange = Data_sht2.Cells(3, 1)

Set pCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
         SourceData:=pivotRange)
Set pTable = pCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=tableRange, _
         TableName:="Tabella_pivot1")
```

Make sure that when you are converting the previous part to this, you know that R5000C10 means "Row 5000 Column 10" (I did not know and this created me some problems).

Then I changed all instances in the original code where "Sheet4" was called and substituted with "Sheet2". Be careful with this, I noticed that if I ran the code from Excel, the newly generated sheet was called "Sheet1", if run by HPQC it was called "Sheet2". Make sure you use the debugger and see how the new sheet is called.

Also be careful that for "Set pivotRange" and "Set tableRange", you cannot give it the sheet name itself, assign the sheet to a variable and then use that.

With all these things combined, the code now works. The postprocessing still doesn't look exactly as I expected but I suspect this is due to changes in ExcelVBA from Excel 2007 to Excel2013 (the pivot table shows the information needed but formatted slightly differently). I hope this will help others in my same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the current documentation for PivotCaches.create [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivotcaches.create.aspx) and you'll see that the method signature looks like this for both versions:

```
PivotCache Create(
    XlPivotTableSourceType SourceType,
    Object SourceData,
    Object Version
)
```

You are setting the PivotTableVersion to 10 explicitly, but the default for both Excel 2010 and 2013 is 12:

> When not supplied, the version of the PivotTable will be
>   xlPivotTableVersion12.

That's almost certainly causing you issues as you move between Excel versions so remove that last argument and let it go to the default for the current version of Excel:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Query1!R1C1:R5000C10").CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Sheet4!R3C1", TableName:="Tabella_pivot1"
```

Also try splitting up that call into multiple statements like what you see in the accepted Answer in this question, it will make it easier to read and also help you understand where it's going wrong:

[VBA: Type Mismatch with PivotCaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094245/vba-type-mismatch-with-pivotcaches)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried removing the version as you said, did not resolve the problem. For the split, I'm getting a Run-time error '424' Object required, putting the code at the bottom of the question.